Python to .EXE Gets flag as malicious
I'm learning Python, and when trying to convert it to an executable, it always gets flagged as malicious. Is there a way to not get flagged? It seems all Python code is malicious just by being Python. I have tried numerous code variations, and it always gets flagged, even a simple print("Hello world").
Things i tried:

Auto-py-to exe - Is the most unreliable.. Gets flagged by everything
Nuitka - Is the better option - only gets flagged by 5 AV (Image below)




We can't help you with that -- it's a question for the authors of the particular AV engines doing the flagging. The issue isn't caused by anything in your code, so it's not really a development problem.

Me as well would assume that is a false positive, I hope others can verify it, maybe you need to add some more details in the exact creation process. Still playing the Devils Advocate, how can you know that your system is not infected and malware was slipped into the exe?

@Daraan, this is actually a common report, so very likely the OP's system isn't infected, but the authors of the detection engines in question saw enough malware that was packaged using py2exe-type tools that they added a signature flagging it, and were willing to accept the collateral harm of innocent software being caught up.

@CharlesDuffy I think it's a relevant question for python packaging; in practice, most "my binary is being flagged as malicious by some antivirus" is the job of the packager to tweak until it stops making them mad, because it's not like McAffee would ever release a good antivirus

@Kaia, ...taking responsibility for maintaining answers that rely on details of a cat-and-mouse game where both sides are modifying proprietary software in deliberately obscure ways is a bad place to be, though: it means answers can go out-of-date at any time, particularly as malware authors take advantage of the advice we give here and detection engines modify their signatures and heuristics to catch up. We want to build a knowledgebase of questions and answers that will remain relevant indefinitely, and this isn't a space where that's going to happen.

@CharlesDuffy That's fair, yeah.

Does this answer your question? Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG

^ That's not a perfect dupe, but it's got good advice to start. I think you might also check the auto-py-to-exe github issues and see if there's any mention of antivirus there?

I recommend to use pyinstaller.

Run into this on multiple separate occasions, the av decides the program is malicious and either needs messaged to stop and they will or they are deliberately pulling the dumb... (MAYBE) you have some kind of virus but I doubt it

Unfortunately pyinstaller was flag as Trojan by 7 AVs. Nuitka only by 5 Avs
